# tools for running test binaries

Tags: unit-testing, stress-testing

I'm looking for a tool that could run a unit test, which is a normal unix binary, as many instances concurrently.  I also need the tool to gather any cores and stop on failure.  Ability to allow some failures is a bonus.

Idea is to stress test a multi-threaded application with a large amount of test processes running concurrently.  A single unit-test crashes very seldom, so I want to run many of them at the same time to maximize my chances of catching the bug.

Extra credit if the tool can be daemonized  to constantly run a set of binaries, with the ability to control it from outside.

UPDATE:

I ended up implementing a test driver with Python (runs multiple tests concurrently, restarting a test if it completes successfully).  The test driver can be signaled to stop by creating a stamp file.  This test driver is in turn invoked by a buildbot builder and stopped when a new revision is published.  This approach seems to work reasonably well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valgrind Maybe ?

http://valgrind.org/

Comment: I think this may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912976/valgrind-automatic-tests-are-they-used-somewhere

Comment: Ah, I'm searching for something along the script mentioned in the answer.